# Assign SharePoint list item to a list of individuals on a rotating basis

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to assign list items to a list of individuals on a rotating basis.

Here is essentially what I am trying to do:

Names: Tom Joe Sam

In a SharePoint list, when a user (other than these three people) adds an item to the list, an email/task would be sent to Tom, and Tom only, column will populate with Tom's name as assigned to that item. The same thing would happen if a new list item is added, but it would be assigned to Joe, and then Sam, and then back to Tom, and so on.

Is there any way to do this in SharePoint designer 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Alerting is a standard feature for SharePoint Task lists, however activation has been removed form the UI in SharePoint 2013.

This article describes how you can enable it using PowerShell:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Enable-email-notifications-390a927c

When the alert feature is enabled, the assigned user will be informed about every change to the task item.

For your use case, Tom needs to set up a notification for himself on the list, so he receives an email for every new item even when it is not assigned to him.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I understand how to set up an alert, e.g. send an email when Tom is assigned. But is is possible for sharepoint to automatically assign to Tom and the next item created automatically assigns to Joe and so on?

Comment: That would require a custom workflow which starts on every new item created. You can create and deploy a workflow with sharepoint designer.
You can also create a ListItem event receiver but that requires Visual Studio and knowledge of C# (or VB)

Comment: I do have sharepoint designer and know how to start workflow when new item is created. would you know how to write the workflow such that assignment **rotates through a list of users** and not just 1 user? for now, I only know how to assign to 1 specific user.

Comment: I'd probably use a second list which only a user field [A] and an integer field [B], Reference all the users there so you have an entry for each rotating user. Set [B] for the first user to 1 (all others 0),The workflow accesses the list items one by one and compares the integer in field [B] to [B] of the next item. If you are at the end of the list, start over at the beginning. As soon as [B] values are diferent, you have the user to notify. Increase [B] of the next User item. If at the end of the list, start from the beginning, imagine the list as a ring. Good luck :)