# Sharepoint list - autopopulate column with predefined looping list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I need to create a sharepoint list for task assignments. There is a predefined list of people to whom task should be assigned (Note: it does not need to be a sharepoint list, its just an example of displaying the needed data - employees names):

[image: Employees]

Ideally, the 'Assigned to:' column would automatically populate in the demonstrated manner:

[image: List to be autopopulated]

Meaning, whenever a user adds a new element, he puts another Task, the assignment is done automatically in the given order. I've tried every idea that I came up with and nothing worked.
Any solution here highly appreciated.

I came up with temporary solution which assings random people [out of given 3] to newly created tasks. Solution + results below:
[image: Power Automate Solution]
Resulting list:
[image: Automated task list]

Now, I need to replace the "rand" function in "Get item" [middle section] in Power Automate with anything that lists employees in given order, not randomly. Please advise

**Working solution:**
[image]

Comment: I've managed to find a similar inquiry with some kind of answer but its not specific enough for me to construct a solution in Power Automate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052950/assign-sharepoint-list-item-to-a-list-of-individuals-on-a-rotating-basis?rq=1
The last comment sort of answers the question - anyone able to explain this in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems kinda basic algoryhtmic problem.

What I suggest :

- First load list of employees (Get Items activity)
- Then use the ID column of the newly inserted item and apply the modulo of number of employees to get the index of the employee to assign the task to
- then grab the nth employee login to assign the task

Comment: Thanks! After a slight modification to modulus formula it actually assigns employees properly. KUDOS